# How to use "polymorphic_url" with a subdomain in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a Rails application deployed to a sub-domain and when I do:

```
polymorphic_url(Model.file)
```

it returns

```
domain.com/.../...
```

However my file is actually at `sub.domain.com/.../...`.

How can I make `polymorphic_url` return the link properly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can provide a `host` argument to override the default; the helper takes the same `options` arguments as [`url_for`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor):

> :host - Overrides the default (current) host if provided.

So you would use:

```
polymorphic_url(Model.file, host: 'sub.domain.com')
```

Try that out and let me know how you get on!

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Thank you!